# MySQL Trigger with a Inner Join

Tags: mysql, join, triggers

I have two tables in mySQL, call them reviews and products. And then I have another table (call it productsmaster) that is an inner join of reviews and products. I am trying to create a trigger to run the inner join query when a new record is added to reviews.

I have tried to just insert the inner join query into the trigger, but it is returning a "#1422 - Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger." error. For clarity of the issue my code for the trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateprodmaster 
AFTER INSERT ON reviews 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
CREATE TABLE productsmaster AS
SELECT products.*, reviews.userid, reviews.usergender, reviews.userage, reviews.score
FROM products
INNER JOIN reviews
ON products.pid=reviews.pid;
END;$$
```

If anyone has any thoughts on this it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Jack

Comment: You are using a 3d table here `user_review.score` which is not JOINED

Comment: Apologies, I misnamed the column it should have been 'reviews'. It is updated now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **`CREATE TABLE`** statement causes an implicit `COMMIT`. And that's not allowed.

There are no easy button workarounds to this limitation.

---

But even if you were able to workaround this limitation, why in the plastic would you want to attempt to create a new table every time a row is inserted?

When a second row is inserted, the trigger would to attempt to (again) create a table of the exact same name (which will fail because a table of that name already exists.)

Back the cart up a bit, behind the horse.

And figure out what requirement you need to meet.

When you get back to needing a trigger, you can burn that bridge when you get to it.

**FOLLOWUP**

If the intent is to attempt to insert a row into `productsmaster` table, whenever a row is inserted into the `reviews` table, using an after insert trigger, we'd need an `INSERT` statement in the trigger body.

The values of the columns of the row (that was just inserted to `reviews`) are available in the trigger. There's no need to select from the `reviews` table. We can reference the column values of the newly inserted row (in an after insert trigger) by qualifying the column names with **`NEW.`**

I recommend avoiding **`.*`**, and explicitly name the columns to be retrieved from `products`. I'm assuming the `pid` column is a unique key (or the primary key) in `products`.

As an example:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE TRIGGER trg_reviews_after_insert 
 AFTER INSERT ON reviews
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO productsmaster (col1, col2, userid, usergender, userage, score)
    SELECT p.col1
         , p.col2
         , NEW.userid
         , NEW.usergender
         , NEW.userage
         , NEW.score
      FROM products p
      WHERE p.pid = NEW.pid;
  END$$

 DELIMITER $$
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. When you put it like that I can see that it probably was not the best plan. I suppose what I want to do is to update the table (which is a join of two tables) when a new record is added to one table. Would a trigger or another method be suitable?

Answer (score 0):

never use the select in triggers , triggers accept only update or insert or delete